# How to undo the dots on this grid?

Tags: javascript, html, css, algorithm

Refering to a live javascript playground at https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/MWrzpav?editors=1011 .When you click on the grid, it will put a triangle or a square depending on your liking using the buttons (triangle & square below the grid). However, I am trying to build a**n Undo function for both triangle and square**. Can anyone offer me some guidance on this?  Thank you for reading and have a nice day :) I use the code below to put square or triangle on the grid.

```
newDot.style.top = y + 'px';
newDot.style.left = x + 'px';
// Add the new element to the end of the body:
document.body.appendChild(newDot);
```

[image]

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to rewrite the app. 1. introduce app state (here: two arrays storing the clicked grid coordinates) 2. user interaction will change the app state, not the DOM 3. after a user interaction, update the DOM according to the app state. Once you do this, undoing the placement of a triangle simply means 1. remove the last element of the triangle array 2. update the DOM to reflect this (i.e. remove all triangles, then add them back based on the state array)

Answer (score 1):

I would use Memento pattern to implement the undo functionality with the classes listed below.

Basically, the client (main function in my example) invokes `const s = Grid.snapshot()` method to take a snapshot of the current state of the Grid, and invokes `History.push(s)` to save the snapshot. When the client needs to undo the change, it retrieves the previous grid state, i.e. snapshot, by invoking `const pre = History.pop()`, and then feed the previous snapshot to the grid by `Grid.restore(pre)`. The `Grid.restore()` method can internally invoke `Grid.render()` method to render the previous state of the grid, i.e. draw the previous set of dots.

**Grid Class**

Grid holds information about the grid, i.e. all the coordinates of the dots, shapes of the dots, etc.

**Snapshot Class**

Snapshot captures the state of the grid at some point in the past. Grid is responsible for producing an instance of Snapshot.

**History Class**

History saves all the previous states of the Grid by storing Snapshot objects. It it essentially a "stack", so it can push or pop a snapshot in a LIFO manner.

**main**

main function handle all the above objects to realize the required functionalities of the app.

---

**UML Diagram**

[image]

---

In order to implement the undo functionality separately for the square and triangle dots, I would tweak this design in such a way that it keeps track of two sets of previous states, one being the triangles and the other being squares. This would result in having two History objects, one recording previous states of square dots and the other recording those of triangle dots, as well as the Grid object producing separate snapshots for squares and triangles.